# Android - How can I be able to get a View that has been added programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, layout, horizontalscrollview

I have the following problem. This is a little sketch  of my layout (only the intereseted part):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
             >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/horizontalLayoutContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now I have added four buttons to the horizontalLayoutContainer ID layout. I want to be able to disable the buttons within the container, but of coarse I'm not :((
How can I get the views related to the Buttons that have been added dinamically?
(I can't use the generateID on the buttons because it is available from API 17).

I have also tried to set the ID manually, starting from 0, and the result is that I'm able to catch the one with ID = 0 but not the others :((
Please help

Thanks

EDIT:
    ViewGroup mLayout = (ViewGroup) ((FragmentActivity) mContext).findViewById(rootLayoutID);

```
                    if(mLayout!=null){
                        for(int i = 0; i <  mLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
                        {
                            View view = mLayout.getChildAt(i);

                            if(!(view instanceof Button))
                                setViewsEnabled(mContext, view.getId(), enable);
                            else{
                                Log.debug(tag, "I'm a button with ID: "+ view.getId());
                                view.setEnabled(enable);
                                view.setClickable(enable);
                            }
                            view.setEnabled(enable);
                        }
                        mLayout.setEnabled(enable);
                    }
                }
```

With this portion of code I'm able to disable everything into my layout except for the buttons. As you can see I've also created a log that is printed 4 times (exactly the number of the button) but with ID = 0;

SOLVED: I've found a solution by assign programmatically (incrementally starting from 0) an ID and then making an if/else as shown below in order to recognize the right activity in which buttons are defined:

```
             /*
              * Se l'istanza e' MainActivity disabilito/abilito manualmente i bottoni
               */
                        if(mContext.getClass() == MainActivity.class){
                            ViewGroup horizontalScrollViewViewGroup = (ViewGroup)
                                    ((FragmentActivity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.horizontalLayoutContainer); 

                            if(horizontalScrollViewViewGroup!=null){
                                Log.debug(tag, "Buttons Number: "+horizontalScrollViewViewGroup.getChildCount());

                                for(int i = 0; i < horizontalScrollViewViewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
                                    View view = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).findViewById(i);
                                    if(view!=null){
                                        view.setClickable(enable);
                                        view.setEnabled(enable);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: SetId() should work, perhaps there is something else in your code. However, you could also use the method getChildAt : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)

Comment: Why do you need an id at all? If you created a `Button` in code, you have a reference to it in code. Just hang on to it.

Comment: I've also tried to use the getChildAt, but the problem is that each element into the horizontalScrollView is set with an inflater dinamically (because I0ve defined the layout of each element into another xml)

Comment: Geobit it is too complex, because in order to have modularity into my code I've preferred not to do everything into one single activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create dynamic view you can assign an id to that view as

```
final int  ID=1001;
Button btn=new Button (this);
btn.setId(ID);
```

and get the view using

```
findviewbyid(ID) ;
```

Comment: I've already tried this way, but the returned view has always ID=0, Not Good :((

Comment: This method works only if you specify the activity in which you have created the component (in this case the button), otherwise it will return always ID=0

Answer (score 0):

View.findViewWithTag can help, but... wait, you added them via addView(View) so you have references to them already

Comment: Yes, I've added them with the addView. In my function I have the Context and the root id of the activity layout as in parameters.

Comment: With this code I'm able to take only the button with ID = 0:
Please have a look at the edit into my post.

Comment: Solved with the setId() method but also by specifing the context in which the setID methon has been invoked :) Thanks really everybody